# How to get rid of run time error on code chef

Tags: python, runtime-error

The following code works fine on both the jupiter notebook and the pycharm but its showing runtime error on codechef. The code is to check whether the permutation is ambiguous or not.

```
for i in range(int(input())):
        n=int(input())
        l=list(map(int,input().split()))
        p=l[:]
        for j in range(n):
            p[l[j]-1]=j+1
        if(p==l):
            print("ambiguous")
        else:
            print("not ambiguous")
```

Comment: If you have an error it's useful to add the error text to your question

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

When posting, it usually helps to add more information, such as the error message itself. Regardless, I pasted your code into Python and I've deduced that the problem arises from the `input()` statement- I'm not sure what 'code chef' is, but it probably doesn't know that the user should input an integer into the `input()` prompt.

Therefore, a workaround is to hardcode your inputs as variables:

```
input1 = "5"
input2 = ...

for i in range(int(input1)):
    n=int(input2)
    ...
```

Comment: Firstly,thanks for the advice.No,the codechef does know how to take the user input ,But it'll give constraints such as limited memory and time and  range of input values ,we have to provide the answer such that it has to be much time efficient for given constrains. It's basically based on algorithms